# How to make only the ::after pseudo element visible in an element?

Tags: html, css

I have got an element with `::after` pseudo element and some text:

```css
#someElement {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#someElement::after {
  content: 'b';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="someElement">a</span>
</div>
```

I want only the letter `b` to be visible. I tried to change `display` and`position`, but it do not work. How can I do that without manipulate `color` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property.

```css
#someElement {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#someElement::after {
  content: 'b';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5rem;
  color: red;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="someElement">a</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `font-size:0` to hide the actual element give the `font-size: 36px;` to the pseudo element

```css
#someElement {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:0;
}

#someElement::after {
  content: 'b';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5rem;
  color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="someElement">a</span>
</div>
```